# Programmatic redirect from Parent route to Child route upon async data delivery (Vuejs)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have two nested routes (one into another) like this

```
{
    path: "posts",
    component: Posts,
    children: [
        {
            path: ":id",
            component: Post,
        }
    ]
}
```

Yes, the listing of posts and area to display an individual post are located next to each other (posts on the left, the individual post area on the right inside `Posts` component). Now upon page loading (url: `/posts/`) I get the posts list on the left and an empty space occupied by `<router-view/>` on the right, so that when I click on a post link from the list I get the full post in the `<router-view/>` on the right and url becomes like `/posts/5/`.

It works fine when I click manually, but I would like to **automatically** click on the first link in the list on the left to redirect from '/posts/' to `/posts/5/` (for example) and display details on the right. **Automatically** on page (app) load. I don't know post ids in advance, so I must wait for them to load. The flow I would like to automate: page `/posts/` shows posts list -> programmed click on the first post link (somehow hooked into async posts request) -> redirect to `/posts/:id/` -> the clicked post details appear on the right.

I tried component hooks & route guards. The problem with hooks is that posts get downloaded in async mode and this process isn't tied to hooks which might have been executed earlier. The same about router guards - the moment of their execution doesn't coincide with async data delivery. Moreover, when I tried to mess with redirecting via `router.push()` upon getting the data inside posts loading async function, I got a bunch of `vue-router` errors and some kind of loop (stack overflow error in the console). I hope I could explain what I want to achieve. What is the right approach? Is it even possible with Vue?

Comment: you should not do `router.push()` instead what you can do is `$route.params.id = yourPostId` this will prevent the duplicate route error.

Comment: @Muhammad should I watch `$route` or it will trigger routing automatically?

Comment: It will not trigger the routing automatically but it will update the url without any errors, you may set currentPost object in your vuex store if you are using vuex store and then get it to a computed property in the component where you want to display it.